# how to remove a portion of a table cell after form tag is closed

Tags: jquery

how can i remove everything after form and before the th is closed

```
<th colspan="2">
  <form method="get" action="" name="ROSTER">
    Show Roster For: 
    <select size="1" name="ROSTER_FRANCHISE" onchange="display_one_roster(this.value);">
      <option value="0005" class="fname0005">Franchise 5</option>
      <option value="0001" selected="selected" class="fname0001">Franchise 1 Long Team Name</option>
      <option value="0002" class="fname0002">Sticks</option>
      <option value="0003" class="fname0003">Tony's Testing Team</option>
      <option value="0004" class="fname0004">Mike's Testing Team</option>
      <option value="0006" class="fname0006">Franchise 6</option>
      <option value="0007" class="fname0007">Franchise 7</option>
      <option value="0008" class="fname0008">Franchise 8</option>
      <option value="0009" class="fname0009">Franchise 9</option>
      <option value="0010" class="fname0010">Franchise 10</option>
      <option value="0011" class="fname0011">Franchise 11</option>
      <option value="0012" class="fname0012">Franchise 12</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  - Rosters out of date?  <a href="javascript:window.location.reload();">Reload this page</a> to get them back in sync.
</th>
```

so i'd like to remove this portion

```
- Rosters out of date?  <a href="javascript:window.location.reload();">Reload this page</a> to get them back in sync.
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and cleanest way would be to put it in a `<div id="roster_check">`

Then remove the div using jQuery as follows:

```
$("#roster_check").remove();
```

The div would of course need to be closed after the last line you want removed.

Comment: i have no access to change the html